# Why the APIMCLI import process give me 403 Forbidden?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am getting "403" forbidden when I try to import an API for my distributed APIM instance.

I have 4 VMs running centos 7 and JDK 8:
1st -  PostgreSQL
2nd -  WSO2 IS with Key manager
3rd -  WSO2 APIMMANAGER (2 instances - APIMStore and APIMPublisher)
4th -  WSO2 APIMWORKER (2 instances - APIMGateway and APIMTrafficManager)

1- After start all servers OK, I create an 'env' for APIMCLI as follows:

```
apimcli add-env -n apimm_hml --registration https://apimmanager:9444/client-registration/v0.14/register --apim https://apimmanager:9444 --token https://apimmanager:8244/token --import-export https://apimmanager:9444/api-import-export-2.6.0-v2 --admin https://apimmanager:9444/api/am/admin/v0.14 --api_list https://apimmanager:9444/api/am/publisher/v0.14/apis --app_list https://apimmanager:9444/api/am/store/v0.14/applications
```

2- I had add my exported APIs to $ .wso2apimcli/esported/apis

3- I get Ok the Tokken from APIM

```
curl -X POST -c cookies http://apimmanager:9764/publisher/site/blocks/user/login/ajax/login.jag -d 'action=login&username=admin&password=admin' -k -v

* About to connect() to apimmanager port 9764 (#0)
*   Trying 10.61.1.68...
* Connected to apimmanager (10.61.1.68) port 9764 (#0)
> POST /publisher/site/blocks/user/login/ajax/login.jag HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: apimmanager:9764
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 42
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
* upload completely sent off: 42 out of 42 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, private
* Added cookie JSESSIONID="E97A1EC2A610C0985E9149C6AEDB0FC9AAF492239437DB11D6A64F0ADBB3CA2424437A19ED8A51409F453D1E53640A547E186AC3810235AD7761DE58093C432314B3D46DE5B353562FBCFEB3268A6084945840CD1083330A69B8564068B92A39B17714D2F94807129392AB6EDFE10CB19EC4ED87E514B31E09D19991F6D6938A" for domain apimmanager, path /publisher, expire 0
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=E97A1EC2A610C0985E9149C6AEDB0FC9AAF492239437DB11D6A64F0ADBB3CA2424437A19ED8A51409F453D1E53640A547E186AC3810235AD7761DE58093C432314B3D46DE5B353562FBCFEB3268A6084945840CD1083330A69B8564068B92A39B17714D2F94807129392AB6EDFE10CB19EC4ED87E514B31E09D19991F6D6938A; Path=/publisher; HttpOnly
< Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
< Content-Length: 17
< Date: Mon, 21 Oct 2019 14:32:47 GMT
< Server: WSO2 Carbon Server
<
* Connection #0 to host apimmanager left intact
{"error" : false}
```

4- I get 403 forbiden afte try to import an API:

```
apimcli import-api -f APIM_ABC_v1.0.zip -e apimm_hml -u admin -p admin -k --preserve-provider=false --verbose

[INFO]: Insecure: true
[INFO]: import-api called
[INFO]: Environment: 'apimm_hml'
[INFO]: Import URL: https://apimmanager:9444/api-import-export-2.6.0-v2/import-api?preserveProvider=false
[INFO]: Source Environment: ConsentimentoService_v1.0.zip
ZipFilePath: /home/centos/.wso2apimcli/exported/apis/ConsentimentoService_v1.0.zip
Error importing API.
Status: 403 Forbidden
Error importing API
[ERROR]: 403 Forbidden
```

From APIMPublisher Log file I get:

```
 WARN {org.owasp.csrfguard.log.JavaLogger} -  potential cross-site request forgery (CSRF) attack thwarted (user:<anonymous>, ip:10.61.1.68, method:POST, uri:/api-import-export-2.6.0-v2/import-api, error:required token is missing from the request) {org.owasp.csrfguard.log.JavaLogger}
```

Answer (score 0):

After the creation of the environment (ie step 1) try to login to the environment using the below command

```
apimcli login <environment> -u <username> -p <password>
```

in your case..
    apimcli login apimm_hml -u admin -p admin -k